# Python: How do I convert a NonType variable to a String?

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
>>> def rule(x):
...     rule = bin(x)[2:].zfill(8)
...     rule = str(rule)
...     print rule
```

I am trying to convert rule into a string, but when I run the following command, here is what I get:

```
>>> type(rule(20))
00010100
<type 'NoneType'>
```

What is a NoneType variable and how can I convert this variable into a string?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to do:

```
def rule(x):
    return bin(x)[2:].zfill(8)
```

All functions return `None` implicitly if no `return` statement was encountered during execution of the function (as it is in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Your rule function doesn't return anything -- it only prints. So, rule(20) returns None -- the python object representing 'no value'. You can't turn that into a string, at least not in the way you are expecting.

You need to define rule to return something, like this:

```
>>> def rule(x):
...    rule=bin(x)[2:].zfill(8)
...    rule=str(rule)
...    return rule
```

Then it will return a string object.